# Can't register: "No user found with matching email"

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, sign-up

I wanted to create a sock puppet account this morning, but it just seems impossible.

I receive the emails after the initial registration just fine, and when I click the link, I get to a page with a big friendly green checkmark which says "your registration was successful" (or the moral equivalent; I closed the window already)

But then, when I try to log in with the email address I created for this purpose, the login page insists that this email address is not registered:

[image]

I tried twice on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ and now finally tried on Ask Ubuntu, and the experience is the same every time.

(It allowed me to register the same email address twice on MSE, too.)

Is it just me, or is registration broken?

(If it's just me, is there something wrong with the domain I'm using? I have another sock puppet registered with the same domain name, so it worked in the past.)

Comment: I don't want to reveal the email address here, but if it helps, I tried the display name SOC Puppet at least on the last two attempts.

Comment: Silly question, but did you make sure to use a separate browser profile, or guest mode, including with the registration confirmation link? (i.e. just clicking it in the same browser as you're now using for this account isn't going to work as it will confirm your main account or something like that.)

Comment: All of this happened on a pristine incognito tab, yes (though I clicked the welcome link in a different browser instance in a different VM, also incognito).

Comment: [No repro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1474067/shadow-sock-number-2024), created that profile just now. So guess only a dev/CM might shed some light.

Comment: Just to make sure again, you opened the confirmation link in the same browser instance as the one where you had [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2mLN.png)? If not, it might be the problem.

Comment: Just now, trying again from my phone, attempting to register at [unix.se], I get "Something went wrong. Please contact us at community-support@stackoverflow.email for assistance."

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda No, my email lives in a different tab entirely, essentially on a different computer.

Comment: So that might be the problem, i.e. the "normal" workflow is the user opening the email and link in same browser.

Comment: I now seem to get "something went wrong" for all my attempts, including with a different email address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sent an email to community support and received the following reply:

> This issue may be caused by using a VPN or proxy. We recommend trying to create an account while disconnected from any VPN or disabling any proxies.
> If you're not using either, please try creating a new account on a different device (one not on the same network, such as a cell phone that's not connected to your local wifi if you've already tried with a computer) and let us know if you run into the same issue.

(Ticket: 123576)

I disabled the VPN on my phone, and was finally able to complete the registration. Once the account is created, I am able to log in with the VPN enabled again.